# Grading logic for checkboxes with multiple correct

Tags: java, checkbox

[Quiz app[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ItwO2y6O-ZDjZgeSV795LeUmK8w45fb/view?usp=sharing)

I have problem with grading logic. I cannot determine why the points are count incorrectly. The code worked fine when I count points in one method. My mentor suggested to check points in separate methods and now I do not get how the app counts the points and how to solve it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ItwO2y6O-ZDjZgeSV795LeUmK8w45fb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: don't link to code - post a minimal code example.